# Scala ListBuffer (or equivalent) shuffle

Tags: arrays, list, scala, shuffle

Is there a simple shuffle function for Scala lists?

If not, whats the simplest way to implement?

I have a lot of these things to do all over the code, so the simpler the call, the best it is

An example in Ruby

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]           #=> [1, 2, 3]
a.shuffle                 #=> [2, 3, 1] returns new array shuffled
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked at using [Collections.shuffle()][1] ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259223/how-to-use-java-collections-shuffle-on-a-scala-array?rq=1

Comment: Hmm, not using java...only scala native functions :)

Comment: @BrianAgnew, that won't work with Scala collections.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Scala you can use [`scala.util.Random`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Random%24.html):

```
util.Random.shuffle((1 to 10).toSeq)
//Vector(9, 6, 8, 7, 10, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4)

util.Random.shuffle(List('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'))
//List(B, D, A, E, C, F)
```

Your results may vary...

Comment: Very nice and clean, but for some reason it didn't worked with Array[Objects], only with Lists and ListBuffers (using 2.8)

Comment: @rodrigo.dk The collection has to be something that implements the trait TraversableOnce. Try ArrayBuffer for example.

Comment: @rodrigo.dk use java.util.Collections.shuffle for arrays

Comment: @LuigiPlinge That's for for java arrays.

Comment: @worldsayshi java and Scala arrays are the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I had the shallow impression that the collections implementations were disparate.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge the signature of `java.util.Collections.shuffle` is `public static void shuffle(List<?> list)`, how can you shuffle an array with that? I suppose you meant `ArrayList`s?

Comment: @Zoltán good point. I don't know the solution off the top of my head; you might like to post a question if google doesn't turn up anything.